# Creating a Calculator using command line interface and malloc,

Tags: c, linux, struct, malloc, command-line-interface

I am working on malloc and command-line interface where I have to create and simple calculator.  I have run the program successfully but I want to print my result from the main, not from the function and I am unable to run it from the main.  Every time when I run it will show garbage value.  What went wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    int num1;
    int num2;
    uint8_t *ope;
    int result;
} Calc;

void SI( Calc c) {
    if(strcmp(c.ope,"add")==0)
    {
        printf(" result is : %d\n :",c.result = (c.num1 + c.num2 ));
    }
    else if(strcmp(c.ope,"sub")==0)
    {
        printf(" result is :%d\n :",c.result = (c.num1 - c.num2 ));
    }
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    Calc *pCalc = (pCalc *) malloc(sizeof(Calc));

    pCalc ->ope = (argv[1]);
    pCalc ->num1   = atoi (argv[2]);
    pCalc ->num2   = atoi (argv[3]);
    SI(*pCalc );

    printf("result is: %d\n", pCalc ->result);  // I want to print result here

    free(pCalc );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make the function `SI` return either the struct or the `int` result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SI(*pCalc );` passes the value of the structure (essentially a copy) to `SI`, and `void SI( Calc c)` declares `SI` to have a parameter `c` that is initialized to the passed value. Changes to `c` in `SI` affect only the parameter `c`; they do not affect the structure in `main`.

You can change `SI(*pCalc );` to `SI(pCalc);` so that it passes the address of `pCalc` instead of its value, and you can change the function declaration to `void SI(Calc *c)` so that its parameter `c` is a pointer and is initialized to the passed address. Inside `SI`, change `c.` to `c->`. The `.` operator accesses a member of a structure, whereas the `->` operator accesses a member of a structure that is pointed to.

Alternatively, you could modify the return type of `SI` so that it returns some result—either the modify structure (return type `Calc`) or just the individual result (return type `int`). Then you would add a `return` statement into the function to return the value, and, in the `main` routine, you could use `x = SI(*pCalc);` to assign the returned value to `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass pointer of `pCalc` to the function `SI` (as suggested by @EricPostpischil) and set its `result` there itself.

Also, added some more fixes. Please read the comments `// CHANGE HERE`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{   int num1;
    int num2;
    uint8_t *ope;
    int result;
} Calc;

// CHANGE HERE - accept pointer argument
void SI(Calc* c) {
    if (c == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    // CHANGE HERE - use strncmp instead of strcmp
    if (strncmp(c->ope, "add", 3) == 0)
    {
        c->result = (c->num1 + c->num2);
    }
    else if (strncmp(c->ope, "sub", 3) == 0)
    {
        c->result = (c->num1 - c->num2);
    }
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    // CHANGE HERE - command line arguments validation
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Unexpected number of arguments\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // CHANGE HERE - pCalc -> Calc
    Calc *pCalc = (Calc *) malloc(sizeof(Calc));

    pCalc ->ope = (argv[1]);
    pCalc ->num1   = atoi (argv[2]);
    pCalc ->num2   = atoi (argv[3]);
    SI(pCalc);  // CHANGE HERE - pass the pointer

    printf("result is: %d\n", pCalc->result);  // I want to print result here

    free(pCalc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alot for your help, Have a nice day